# TransferText Import CSV to Access with EXTRA commas?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to import a CSV Comma delimited file into Access using the TransferText method.

I am however getting mixed up cells - and that is apparently because the CSV contain's comma's for numbers larger than 1000. It obviously thinks at the 1,000 comma that the cell is done and moves to the next. Is there any way I can work around this??

EXAMPLE:

```
ID,Cost
1,$300.00
2,$250.00
3,$3,500.00
```

Comment: This is an example of the Bane of CSV files. Whatever the source of your data is needs to either export with text qualifiers, or use a different delimination character.  The only other way is to read the file as an entire line and create your own parsing method.

Comment: tab delimited text files work much better than CSV files

Comment: Agreed Linger, where I work they have become partial to pipe | delimited files.  Personally I am fan of good old fashioned fixed width files.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the format like the example below and it works much better.

```
"ID","Cost"
"1","$300.00"
```

Comment: O oops.  well then maybe there are people as dumb as me out there that don't know what is the meaning of "text qualifiers".  I will leave this up for them.  :)